# Having trouble with Xcode Autolayout

Tags: xcode, autolayout

[image: That is what program look like in portrait,and it work pretty well.]
That is what program look like in portrait,and it work pretty well.

[image: That is what it look like when I rotate.]
That is what it look like when I rotate.

[image: It's really odd. I did add constraint to the top, but when I rotated the device even the "battery bar",I suppose it's named like this, went away!!]

It's really odd. I did add constraint to the top, but when I rotated the device even the "battery bar",I suppose it's named like this, went away!!

Plz, could someone tell me did I miss anything? Or what can probably change the position of "battery bar".

(After solving the problem:
I find out that when user rotate the device the "battery bar" are suppose to be disappear. And there is way to keep it from disappearing as the asking given below.
I find a way to debug my view by watching "Debugging in Xcode 6" in 2014WWDC.
[2014WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)
)

Comment: Did you get any messages in the console about unsatisfiable constraints? (I'm wondering if there was also some bottom constraint here that pushed everything off the top, but if it did that, there would have been a warning on the console). Anyway, the first step is to figure out where the missing labels went. An easy way to do that is to run the app on simulator, pause (not stop) execution, and then at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`. Also check out `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`.

Comment: Your answer gave me a hint in my way of seeking solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add label to View and embed buttons in UIVIew from Editor>EmbedIn>View. Make View with buttons subView center Horizontally and Vertically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you have a constraint for the label as well? i think the best way to do it is setup the constraints for the label to top margin, and constraint the keypad with equal distance to the label.